# Need to achieve the below output using Kusto Query language(KQl)

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, askql

Sample Data. We are expected to receive Products everyday with Total counts.

| TimeStamp | Product Desc | Product Code | Available count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-02T09:00:00Z | Berries | 111 | 10 |
| 2022-01-02T09:00:00Z | Chocolate | 222 | 20 |
| 2022-01-02T09:00:00Z | Mayo | 333 | 30 |
| 2022-01-03T09:00:00Z | Berries | 111 | 15 |
| 2022-01-03T09:00:00Z | Chocolate | 222 | 22 |
| 2022-01-04T09:00:00Z | Berries | 111 | 30 |

If no product received on that particular day, i have to show the last date received product as the current day.

| TimeStamp | Product Desc | Product Code | Available count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-03T09:00:00Z | Berries | 111 | 15 |
| 2022-01-03T09:00:00Z | Chocolate | 222 | 22 |
| 2022-01-03T09:00:00Z | Mayo | 333 | 30 |
| 2022-01-04T09:00:00Z | Berries | 111 | 30 |
| 2022-01-04T09:00:00Z | Chocolate | 222 | 22 |
| 2022-01-04T09:00:00Z | Mayo | 333 | 30 |

Comment: In other words, you need the last record for each product. You can use `arg_max()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
datatable (['TimeStamp']:datetime,['Product Desc']:string,['Product Code']:int,['Available count']:int)
[
     '2022-01-02T09:00:00Z' ,'Berries'   ,111 ,10
    ,'2022-01-02T09:00:00Z' ,'Chocolate' ,222 ,20
    ,'2022-01-02T09:00:00Z' ,'Mayo'      ,333 ,30
    ,'2022-01-03T09:00:00Z' ,'Berries'   ,111 ,15
    ,'2022-01-03T09:00:00Z' ,'Chocolate' ,222 ,22
    ,'2022-01-04T09:00:00Z' ,'Berries'   ,111 ,30
]
| summarize arg_max(['TimeStamp'], *) by ['Product Code']
```

| Product Code | TimeStamp | Product Desc | Available count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 333 | 2022-01-02T09:00:00Z | Mayo | 30 |
| 222 | 2022-01-03T09:00:00Z | Chocolate | 22 |
| 111 | 2022-01-04T09:00:00Z | Berries | 30 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4WRzQrCMBCE74W%20w95iJUKa6kFv/lwFwZ4sRdI2aKBpJE3Fig/vVi9qkSZhYCf7JQNbCIc7KyWMEhIrLfdO6AtJF4Vw0mFNE7KzpmhyBxtZ53hTO6uq04e/NoVEX1UOzeVVqPL1YG6ayr39wPcS34NuEc44n7BwwnjM5gvG8BwIULKS1ipZE%20yhYRiisDdC/yLrs8lNiUGx4JyjDCJb0RryCgI0iiKUPhINBZsNIf1gvIdMB37pgqW%2094C60VpYdZcg7Omoxe17UhTGAWQt/M7jCfrh7QLaAQAA)

Comment: If this is something you want to do in most of your queries, then please consider creating an [arg_max Materialized View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-overview).