# KQL Query - logins after a url click

Tags: email, kql, askql, kqlmagic

I am trying to build a query that will show user logons after a successful url click.

I want to be able to add the email and recipient and then show if the recipient clicked on the url within the email and then list, for example, the next 10 logins performed by the user that performed the click.

I think I am almost there.

Wierdly everytime I run this I get different results. Can anyone assist?

```
EmailEvents
| where SenderFromAddress contains "example@example.com"
| where RecipientEmailAddress contains "bob.smith"
| project TimeEmailRecieved = Timestamp, Subject, SenderFromAddress, AccountName =       tostring(split(RecipientEmailAddress, "@")[0]), NetworkMessageId
| join ( 
UrlClickEvents 
| where AccountUpn contains "bob.smith"
| where Workload == "Email"
| where ActionType == "ClickAllowed" or IsClickedThrough != "0"
| project Url, UrlChain, ActionType, NetworkMessageId, TimeOfClick = Timestamp ) on NetworkMessageId
| join (
//Merge EmailEvents table with IdentityLogonEvents table a
IdentityLogonEvents
| project UserLogons = Timestamp, AccountName, DeviceName, IPAddress, Location, LogonType
) on AccountName
//Check any logons within 30 minutes of the user recieving the email
| where (UserLogons - TimeOfClick) between (0min.. 15m)
```

I think I am almost there,

Wierdly everytime I run this I get different results. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Can you provide a dataset for which you see this happening?

Comment: Hi Daniel,  Not sure what you mean sorry. These tables are in Microsoft Defender and I am using Advanced Hunting. I want the query to tell me what logins happened directly after the user clicked on a url within an email :)

Comment: I mean, you can add an example dataset like here for instance - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71324317/929164

The best way to get these questions answered is to provide a reproducible example (dataset and expected output).
It doesn't need to be the complete example, just something to work with...

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the KQL you have because I have no access to the data, but there is a smart way to calculate between timestamps. I think you can move on from here using these `extend` after your query:

```
| extend minutes_ago = datetime_diff('minute', UserLogons, TimeOfClick)
| extend clicked_in_15min = minutes_ago < 15
```

You'd have to check the output of the column `minutes_ago` because this either might be negative or positive. According to this, change the `clicked_in_15_min` to the right boolean condition.